# Display posts from multiple value in meta separated by comma

Tags: wp-query, post-meta

I have got main product with meta key: **addons** and meta values in this key: **129456,968945,495435** Each of these three numbers is the key with these meta values. For example:

Post 1: meta_key: **subproduct** meta_value: **129456**

Post 2: meta_key: **subproduct** meta_value: **968945**

Post 3: meta_key: **subproduct** meta_value: **495435**

And now I want to display these three posts in the main product. My code:

```
<?php if (!empty($addons = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'addons', true))):?>
<?php
$params = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_key' => 'subproduct',
    'meta_value' => $addons
);
$wc_query = new WP_Query($params); 
?>

<?php while ($wc_query->have_posts()) : $wc_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php include(rh_locate_template('inc/parts/woomain.php')); ?>  
<?php endwhile; ?>


<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>   
<?php endif;?>
```

With one meta value it worked but with several it doesn't work anymore. How do you view these three posts?

Answer (score 0):

The meta field **Addon** have the meta value `129456,968945,495435` as string. To use this value in a meta query, you should split the value into an array. Like `array( 129456, 968945, 495435 )`.

WordPress have a very good function `wp_parse_id_list()`, which can split comma separated items into array.

```php
<?php if ( ! empty( $addons = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'addons', true ) ) ) : ?>
<?php
$params = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_key' => 'subproduct',
    'meta_value' => wp_parse_id_list( $addons )
);
$wc_query = new WP_Query($params); 
?>

<?php while ($wc_query->have_posts()) : $wc_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php include(rh_locate_template('inc/parts/woomain.php')); ?>  
<?php endwhile; ?>


<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>   
<?php endif;?>
```